# Compare object with an array with another array

Tags: c#, linq

I have a model Group:

```
public class GroupModel
{
    [Key]
    public int GroupModelId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual ICollection<FocusArea> FocusAreas { get; set; }

    ...
```

And a model Focus:

```
public class FocusArea
{
    public int FocusAreaId { get; set; }
    public FocusEnum Focus { get; set; }

    public List<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set;  }

    public virtual ICollection<GroupModel> GroupModel { get; set; }


public enum FocusEnum
{
    Psych,
    Medical,
    LivingWith
}
```

Group and Focus has a many-to-many relationship. My Controller is receiving:

```
public ActionResult GroupSearch(string[] focusSelected) // Values possible are Pysch, Medical and LivingWith
{
    List<GroupModel> groups;

    ...
```

Problem: I want to select the groups that have all the focus that are inside the `focusSelected` array.

What I've tried:

```
groups = groups.Where(t => t.FocusAreas.Where(x => focusSelected.Contains(x.Focus))).ToList()).ToList();
```

Obviously not working. Does anyone have another idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you

```
 var result = groups.Where(g => g.FocusAreas.All(f => focusSelected
              .Any(fs => (FocusEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(FocusEnum), fs, true) == f.Focus)));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Where` needs a delegate / expression that returns `bool`. In your sample - you are putting `Where` inside `Where`, where `Where` returns collection.
Changing inner `Where` to `All` should do the trick:

```
var allSelParsed = focusSelected.Select(s => (FocusEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(FocusEnum), s)
                                .ToList();
groups = groups.Where(gr => allSelParsed.All(selected => 
                                                gr.FocusAreas.Any(fc => 
                                                                    fc.Focus == selected)))
               .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you expected result

```
var result = groups.Where(g => 
                      focusSelected.All(fs => 
                          g.FocusAreas.Any(fa => fa.ToString() == fs)));
```